# SQL: how to list values of a column that are not the 5 most occurring value of that same column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery

I understand how to display the 5 most occurring value of a column like so:

```
select top 5 col1, count(col1)
from table1
group by col1
order by count(col1) desc;
```

However, how do I create a query that displays all other values of the same column that are not in the result of the above query?

I tried the following sub query:

```
select col1
from table1
where col1 not in 
    (select top 5 col1, count(col1)
     from table1
     group by col1
     order by count(col1) desc);
```

However the query failed and I got the following error message:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Which version of Sql Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Sql Server 2012+` you can use `offset`:

```
select col1, count(col1)
from table1
group by col1
order by count(col1) desc
offset 5 rows
```

You may want to add tiebreaker to your ordering here to make it deterministic:

```
select col1, count(col1)
from table1
group by col1
order by count(col1) desc, col1
offset 5 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you cannot select more than one column inside `subquery`.

```
(select top 5 col1, count(col1)..
```

You can remove the `count(col1)` from subquery but `NOT IN` clause can fail when `col1` in `subquery` has `NULL` values

Try changing like this

```
with cte as
(
select top 5 col1
from table1
group by col1
order by count(col1) desc
)
select * from table1 A
where not exists (select 1 from cte B where a.Col=b.col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`OFFSET`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385(v=sql.110).aspx)

```
select col1, count(col1)
from table1
group by col1
order by count(col1) desc
OFFSET 5 ROWS -- skip 5 rows, must use with order by
```